# Table with fixed border-cells

Tags: html, css, html-table

## Intent

1. I want to draw a table using all available horizontal and vertical space (so to say the whole browser window minus margins and page header etc.).
2. The table should resize dynamically when the browser window is resized.
3. It should not be wider or longer than the page, instead it should scroll the content if the content is larger then the cell. These cells are marked with arrows in the graphic below.
4. Cells without an arrow in a direction should neither change their size nor scroll in that direction but be fixed. Hence the table header should only become wider or narrower and the left and right stripes should only change their length.

[image: Like this].

btw: I'm looking for a pure CSS/HTML-Solution?

## Naïve try

I thought it would be HTML 101: [Example](http://cssdesk.com/43raW), but the table just grows until the whole content is shown, the height/width size is just ignored
css:

```
/* structure */
table {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 80%;
}
.right, .left {
    width: 200px;
}
.thead > td, .tfoot > td {
    height: 200px;
}
.center, .tbody > td {
  overflow: auto;
}

/* content boxes */
#content_lu, #content_ru, #content_lb, #content_rb {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#content_cu, #content_cb {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
}
#content_lm, #content_rm {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
}
#content_cm {
    background-color: red;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

and html:

```
<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <td class="left"><div id="content_lu"></div></td>
        <td class="center"><div id="content_cu"></div></td>
        <td class="right"><div id="content_ru"></div></td>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr>
        <td class="left"><div id="content_lm"></div></td>
        <td class="center"><div id="content_cm"></div></td>
        <td class="right"><div id="content_rm"></div></td>
    </tr></tbody>
    <tfoot><tr>
        <td class="left"><div id="content_lb"></div></td>
        <td class="center"><div id="content_cb"></div></td>
        <td class="right"><div id="content_rb"></div></td>
    </tr></tfoot>
</table>
```

## Div-Try

I was able to satisfy all conditions for the first row using absolutely positioned corner divs and a center div using margin-left and -right to box it into the parent div. But I can't position e.g. the last centered div because absolutely positioned it would not be bound by the parent div. [Example](http://cssdesk.com/sx9jJ)

css:

```
/* Structure */
div.main {
   position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 80%;
}

/* corners */
div.top.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;        top: 0;
    width: 200px;   height: 200px;
}
div.top.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;        top: 0;
    width: 200px;   height: 200px;
}
div.bottom.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;        bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;   height: 200px;
}
div.bottom.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;       bottom: 0;
    width: 200px;   height: 200px;
}

/* edges */
div.top.center {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.bottom.center {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.middle.left {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
div.middle.right {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* center */
div.middle.center {
    margin-top: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* Content boxes */
#content_lu, #content_ru, #content_lb, #content_rb {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#content_cu, #content_cb {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
}
#content_lm, #content_rm {
    background-color: green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 800px;
}
#content_cm {
    background-color: red;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top    left">  <div id="content_lu"></div></div>
    <div class="top    center"><div id="content_cu"></div></div>
    <div class="top    right"> <div id="content_ru"></div></div>
    <div class="middle left">  <div id="content_lm"></div></div>
    <div class="middle center"><div id="content_cm"></div></div>
    <div class="middle right"> <div id="content_rm"></div></div>
    <div class="bottom left">  <div id="content_lb"></div></div>
    <div class="bottom center"><div id="content_cb"></div></div>
    <div class="bottom right"> <div id="content_rb"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are directly asking answer for your question!!, instead of showing what have you tried, it would be appreciated if you shows us what you have did or tried, so that we can start help you from there

Comment: @hoffmann: do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/VsA33/1/ ?

Comment: `webkit-scroll` is your answer. But it is not supported by all the browser. but you can achieve this by css2, by creating two elements, the outer one `overflow:hidden' and inner element set to be 'overflow:scroll'

Comment: @AtalShrivastava What is "webkit-scroll"? I only find webkit-overflow-scrolling which only seems to be important for touch devices.

Comment: @abhitalks That example does not scroll vertically and does not expand vertically.

Comment: @Hoffmann: "expand"? you never mentioned that in your question. In fact your question is not very clear. the example i made, does fulfill all your scroll criteria. which browser are you using?

Comment: @abhitalks Thanks for your hint. I do have to clearify myself. Sorry for that, I'm hasseling with that problem for three days I seem to have lost focus.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use `table` elements or would you consider some other HTML mark-up if it achieves the same layout?

Comment: I'd absolutely use any other layout instrument, I will post my attempt with divs for which I could layout the first row in the way that I want it.

Comment: [link](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css3-webkit-vertical-scrollbars/) this will help you to get the understanding on `-webkit-scrollbar`

Comment: @AtalShrivastava This does not seem to touch my problem or do I just not get it? `-webkit-scrollbar` is about scrollbar-styling, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of realizing the layout using absolute positioning.

For the HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="top">top</div>
        <div class="mid">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bot">bot</div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="top">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="mid">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bot"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="top">top</div>
        <div class="mid">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bot">bot</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and for the CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    right: 200px;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.top {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: cyan;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.mid {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.bot {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: cyan;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/sfrXp/

Note: I set the height and certain position offsets to 50px instead of 200px because the 
jsFiddle panels are a bit small, but the concept will still work.

To deal with content overflowing the cells, set `overflow: auto` and `height: 100%` to the block level element holding the content, `p` in this example.

You may also need to assign `height: 100%` to the `body` and `html` tags to define the vertical dimension of the root (screen) element.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I adapted your code so it looks like my two examples. http://cssdesk.com/G3N4r